# Why does a custom route appears twice in Nelmio API Doc?

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

I've tried defining a custom route name for one of my APIs and since then, the API Doc displays that route twice. Any ideas why?

Here's the definition of my API:

```
/**
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   description = "Sends the support email to the HelpDesk address",
 *   statusCodes = {
 *     204 = "Returned when successful",
 *     400 = "Returned when the parameters are incorrect",
 *     401 = "Returned when the token is invalid",
 *     500 = "Returned when there's an internal server error"
 *   },
 *   input="AppBundle\Form\Type\SupportEmailType"
 * )
 * @Post("/support-requests")
 * @Rest\View ()
 */
public function postSupportAction(Request $request)
```

and here's how the route shows up in my doc:
[image]

And this is my `routing.yml` file:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
NelmioApiDocBundle:
   resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
   prefix:   /api/doc
user:
    type:     rest
    resource: AppBundle\Controller\UserController
```

Comment: Can you post the routing.yml settings as well?

Comment: @AlexandruCosoi I've updated the question with the content of my routing.yml file

Comment: I can't recall the last time I used FOSRestBundle but I'm going to take a crapshoot that you have the route defined twice somewhere, as per this issue : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/813

Comment: @Sebastian what is the namespace of @Post("/support-requests")?

Comment: @AlexandruCosoi it's the one mentioned of Symfony's website: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/7-manual-route-definition.html and it looks like this `use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Post;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it the only thing that comes to mind as having the potential to do this is the first part of your routing.yml

try removing this from your routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

I think this code, and the separated definition of the user route makes nelmio see the route twice. I had a similar problem some time ago and I think this was the reason. Sorry for the amount of questions I had to ask but i needed to see the full picture.

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: Să trăiești! :D a mers!

Comment: Cu placere :) . Have fun